# Hyperledger Fabric 0.6 pbft Consensus

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have a Hyperledger fabric (v0.6) network setup on remote machines. I want to enable pbft consensus for commitment of blocks. I can see the pbft consensus enabled in the logs and the peers are able to connect to the root node. I deployed my chaincode on all the 4 peers and invoked a transaction on one. I don't see any commits in any of the peers even after a long time, though the peers propagate state change a lot.

Following is my docker-compose.yml file at the root node:

```
membersrvc:
   image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc
   restart: unless-stopped
   ports:
    - "7054:7054"
   expose:
     - "7054"
   volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
   environment:
     - MEMBERSRVC_CA_ACA_ENABLED=true
   command: membersrvc

  vp0:
     image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
     restart: unless-stopped
     volumes:
       - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
     environment:
        - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0
        - CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=false
        - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLID=test_vp0
        - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLSECRET=MwYpmSRjupbT
        - CORE_PEER_PKI_ECA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
        - CORE_PEER_PKI_TCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
        - CORE_PEER_PKI_TLSCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
        - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
        - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=dev
        - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug  #critical, error, warning, notice, info, debug
        # The following section enables pbft consensus
        - CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_BATCHSIZE=1
        - CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_K=2
        - CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_MODE=classic
        - CORE_PEER_VALIDATOR_CONSENSUS_PLUGIN=pbft  # noops, pbft
        - CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_TIMEOUT_REQUEST=10s
        # - CORE_NOOPS_BLOCK_TIMEOUT=2s
        # - CORE_NOOPS_BLOCK_WAIT=2s
     ports:
        - "7050:7050"
        - "7051:7051"
     expose:
        - "7051"
        - "7052"
        - "7053"
     links:
        - membersrvc
     command: sh -c "sleep 20; peer node start"
```

And this is the docker-compose.yml file at each of the peer nodes:

```
vp1:
     image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
     restart: unless-stopped
     volumes:
       - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
     environment:
        - CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE=root-node-ip:7051
        - CORE_PEER_ID=vp1
        - CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=false
        - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLID=test_vp1
        - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLSECRET=MwYpmSRjupbT
        - CORE_PEER_PKI_ECA_PADDR=http://root-node-ip:7054
        - CORE_PEER_PKI_TCA_PADDR=http://root-node-ip:7054
        - CORE_PEER_PKI_TLSCA_PADDR=http://root-node-ip:7054
        - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
        - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=dev
        - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug  #critical, error, warning, notice, info, debug
        # The following section enables pbft consensus
        - CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_BATCHSIZE=1
        - CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_K=2
        - CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_MODE=classic
        - CORE_PEER_VALIDATOR_CONSENSUS_PLUGIN=pbft  # noops, pbft
        - CORE_PBFT_GENERAL_TIMEOUT_REQUEST=10s
        #- CORE_NOOPS_BLOCK_TIMEOUT=2s
        #- CORE_NOOPS_BLOCK_WAIT=2s
     ports:
        - "7050:7050"
        - "7051:7051"
     expose:
        - "7051"
        - "7052"
        - "7053"
     command: sh -c "sleep 20; peer node start"
```

Can anybody please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that the peers were unable to perform handshake using their docker-published ip addresses . I turned off the auto detection by setting the `CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT` to false and let the peers discover each other by setting the `CORE_PEER_ADDRESS` to the instance's public ip and the `CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE` to the ip address of the validator with which the peer would sync its ledger.